# Handling javascript events for a complex web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

**Scenario 1:**

Consider a webpage with complex UI comprising dynamic dropdowns, drag-n-drop fields, spot-edit kinda form inputs, invoking dialog popups and then triggering click events for dynamic rows additions/remove on the fly etc., I use jquery, jquery UI, bootstrap and select2 at the front-end. Such interface will have so many 'click' events and other event handlers all over the DOM. Some events are registered on dom ready itself and some after the part of interface is being loaded.

**Questions:**

1. Is it OK to let DOM have many events attached?
2. Will this cause any memory leak, browser slow down issue?

**Scenario 2:**

A popup dialog will have dynamic row addition & removal. First, to invoke a dialog popup on button click, I add 'onclick=addPopupEvents()' to the button. The addPopupEvents function will also have the other events registered for DOM elements within the popup component. Suppose, if there is 'add row below' button inside the popup, I add the corresponding events inside the addPopupEvents() function. When I close the popup, I call another function removePopupEvents() to deregister/remove these events that are not required when popup is hidden.

**Questions:**

1. Am I doing it in a right way on removing events?
2. I am not sure that removePopupEvents() is really required. Is it necessary to clear all the events when not in use?

HTML:

```
<div><input type="button" value="dialog" onclick="addDialogevents.registerall('#dialog-modal')" /></div>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display:none">
<div class="cl"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="addDialogevents.deregister('#dialog-modal')">close dialog</a></div>
  <div id="records">
  </div>
  <div><a id="add-row" href="javascript:void(0)">Add record</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { font:normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
div#records div { margin:10px 0; }
.cl { text-align:right; }
a { color:#06c !important; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none }
.cl a { font-size:11px; }
```

JS:

```
var addDialogevents = {
    registerall: function(id){
        $(id).dialog({
          height: 300,
          modal: true
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".remove-row", function (e) {
            $(this).closest('div').remove();
        });

        $('#add-row').on('click',function(){
            $('<div><input type="text" size="20" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="remove-row" href="javascript:void(0)"><b>x</b></a></div>').appendTo('#records');
        });
    },
    deregister: function(id){
        $(id).dialog('close');
        $('.remove-row').off('click');
        $('#add-row').off('click');
        $('#records').empty();
    }
}
```

I am a newbie in advance javascript. Any suggestions/guidance appreciated.

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` ? See http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

Comment: I have posted sample source for scenario #2 at:
http://jsfiddle.net/ybret/

Please download the source, use in local drive and run.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addDialogevents is not defined `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first question: 
Is it OK to let DOM have many events attached?**

Have you tried event delegation? You attach a single event to the parent element of your project, then run checks against what is going on... since you're using jQuery here's a quick example:

```
$('#myProject').on('click mousemove mouseenter', function(e){
     switch (e.type){
          case 'click' : console.log('click'); break;
          case 'mousemove' : console.log('mousemove'); break;
          case 'mouseenter' : console.log('mouseenter'); break;
     };
});
```

log the event to your console to see what you have to work with for running checks. Typically you'll want to work with the target element and the event type to figure out what your code should do.

**You second question:
Am I doing it in a right way on removing events?**

What you're looking for is called Event Namespacing:

http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Basically, when you attach an event you name it - so you can detach it later:

```
$('#Button').on('click.myNameSpace', function(){ ... });
$('#Button').off('click.myNameSpace', function(){ ... });
```

Hope this helps a bit :)

Comment: sorry that my first question misinterpreted! Its not attaching multiple events to one element but actually means, attaching events to so many DOM elements (like menus,buttons etc., ) in the interface.

Comment: no misunderstanding :) event delegation solves the problem of working with a ton of events. You bind 1 event, then use it to check what is happening to your menus, buttons, etc. within your interface (clicks, hovers, etc). :)

Comment: I am trying to group events by UI components. In the above example,  I use addDialogevents.registerall() for Dialog component. So, for event handing of elements inside a table structure, I would write addTableevents.registerall(). This is something like nested rules in LESS CSS. I do this for the sake of web developer's best practice, although I don't know it really worth doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Try `addDialogevents` as global object ? http://jsfiddle.net/ybret/1/